How to declare `syn::PathArguments.Parenthesized` field in structure in Rust?
I surely need to do some serious reading about the way syn works but looks like there isn't a lot of information about it. I hope someone with better knowledge can help.
I am writing some tests for a macro which checks the Field.ty of the TokenStream and takes a relevant action. I can declare struct field types to test PathArguments::None and PathArguments::AngleBracketed (e.g. for PathArguments::AngleBracketed this works
#[derive(MyMacroThatChecksPathArguments)]
pub struct WithAngleBracketPath {
    map_field: HashMap<String, String>,
}

and I get this (with the irrelevant parts removed) Field { ..., ident: Some(Ident { ident: "map_field"}), ty: Type::Path { path: Path { ..., arguments: PathArguments::AngleBracketed ...)
but I am struggling to do something similar for PathArguments::Parenthesized. I feel like I need to get something like the following but surely that doesn't work (what's Fn, right?)
pub struct WithParenthesizedPath {
    par_field: Fn(String, String) -> String,
}

Any help/pointers would be highly appreciated, thanks
UPDATE
This is an extract from the macro code I am trying to test, full implementation is available here
match field.ty {
            Type::Path(ref type_path) => {
                let type_path_quoted = type_path.path.segments.iter().map(|segment| {
                    let segment_ident = &segment.ident;
                    match &segment.arguments {
                        PathArguments::None => quote! { #segment_ident :: },
                        PathArguments::AngleBracketed(angle_args) => quote! { #segment_ident::#angle_args :: }
                        _ => Error::new(segment.arguments.span(), "Can only handle <> type path args").to_compile_error()
                    }
                });

This code only checks the top level path segment.
I'm trying to reach _ => Error::new(segment.arguments.span(), "Can only handle <> type path args").to_compile_error().
Using the code suggested by @FinnBear
WithParenthesizedPath {
     par_field: Box<dyn Fn(String, String) -> String>, 
}

ends up matching the line before the one I need (PathArguments::AngleBracketed(angle_args) => quote! ...) which means I need to have the (A, B) -> C not to be bracketed, if that's possible at all.

If you've tried something, a concrete error message related to a syntax issue might help! Note the semantic issue that traits like Fn(String, String) -> String can't be used as a field type. You could write Box<dyn Fn(String, String) -> String> instead.

Hey Finn, thank, I'm sure out of my depth here. Trying with Box<...> gives me the trait bound error but I believe that even if I fix that and implement a parser for Box<...> I'll still end up with the top level Path being of type AngleBracketed whereas I need to catch Parenthesized.
I am not even sure I can catch that but the macro I am testing handles PathArguments::None and PathArguments::AngleBracketed but raises for _ which at the moment is PathArguments::Parenthesized

Problem here is that I'm trying to declare something I don't even know how to or if it's possible at all

It's ok, but in order to efficiently help, we need to see the error messages and, ideally, a minimum-reproducible example (including the macro code). FYI this code does compile pub struct WithParenthesizedPath {     par_field: Box<dyn Fn(String, String) -> String>, } so I'm not sure why you would get a "trait bound error."

I think the best option is to check the macro expansion but not require it to compile successfully. Unfortunately this is testing implementation and not behavior.

My bad, thanks for answers, I'll update the question to be more specific and give the example. And yes @FinnBear I got your code to compile but the macro code catches it as PathArguments::AngleBracketed. Please check the updated question later, thanks
